# Unable to Access Spark WEB UI and History Server UI

Tags: linux, apache-spark, vmware

I failed to access spark master web UI and spark history server UI from chrome browser on my host machine.

spark master web UI:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LUxu.png)

spark history server UI:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usdiW.png)

The spark application is running on a cluster setup of 3 nodes, which are 3 ContOS virtual machines running on VMware. The host machine is Windows.

I tried:

1. From host machine, I pinged master node and it succeeded:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0u83.png)
2. In master node, I checked if port numbers were correct and if services were listening. It seems they worked fine:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f29ks.png)

Comment: Check what entries you have in the `hosts` file on the master node. Also try to access using IP address.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I tried to access using IP address and it succeeded. Therefore, the problem was the host name was not added to the host file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Vikramsinh Shinde 's reply. The problem was that the host name was not added to the host file. Either adding the host name to the host file or using IP address to access can solve the problem.